# Camerax соотношение 9:16

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Хочу делать фотографии с camerax с пропорциями 9:16 в разрешении 1080x1920.

Но как это сделать? В классе `AspectRatio` есть только

```
    /** 4:3 standard aspect ratio. */
    public static final int RATIO_4_3 = 0;
    /** 16:9 standard aspect ratio. */
    public static final int RATIO_16_9 = 1;
```

Из-за этого моя фотка в 1080x1920 становится в 1920x1080, библиотека трансформирует её под 16:9.

Есть какое нибудь адекватный способ выставить отношение 9:16 в `ImageCapture.Builder`, пока только думал насчёт того чтобы самому руками переворачивать фотку.

Answer (score 0):

У меня вот так:
`imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder() .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY) .setTargetRotation(view?.display?.rotation ?: 0) .setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_16_9) .build()`

Думаю, что .setTargetRotation - Ваш вариант.